# Check file has not been tracked (and deleted) before adding it to git

Tags: git

Is there a way to check before adding the file, the path is not known to git previously in its history?

```
x220:/tmp$ cd git-test
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/git-test/.git/
x220:/tmp/git-test$ scrot IMG_0001.jpg
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git add IMG_0001.jpg
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git commit -a -m import
[master (root-commit) 76c4201] import
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 IMG_0001.jpg
x220:/tmp/git-test$ # view IMG_0001.jpg and actually i dont like it
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git rm IMG_0001.jpg
rm 'IMG_0001.jpg'
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git commit -a -m pruned
[master 57d4fc5] pruned
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 IMG_0001.jpg
x220:/tmp/git-test$ # but what happens, if I accidentally import the file again from my camera?
x220:/tmp/git-test$ scrot IMG_0001.jpg
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        IMG_0001.jpg

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git add IMG_0001.jpg # don't want to do this!
x220:/tmp/git-test$ git commit -a -m import
[master 03932ba] import
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 IMG_0001.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your test:

```
git whatchanged | grep -q $'D\tIMG_0001.jpg'
```

Caveat: `$'...'` is a bashism. If this is a POSIX script you'll have to use a literal `TAB` instead of `\t`.

And here's a content-based one that checks if the contents of the image were checked in as any file before:

```
git show $(git hash-object IMG_0001.jpg) >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with:

```
test "$(git log --oneline -- $file | wc -l)" -gt 0
```

To figure out if the **file** has been seen before. Please feel free to scruntinize my [script](http://s.natalian.org/2015-05-23/check.sh).